# Deleting entire duplicate rows with conditions and

Tags: vba, excel

I have data with duplicates (column "c") and I want to delete the row that has numbers in column "D". but only for the duplicates with odd dates, as seen in the picture
[image]

this is the code im using, but i dont know how to delete the row with data in "D" **and** is a duplicate

```
 Sub del_doops()
    Dim RowNdx As Long
    Dim RowNdx2 As Long

    For RowNdx = Range("A1:f1").End(xlDown).Row To 2 Step -1
        For RowNdx2 = RowNdx - 1 To 1 Step -1   'Begin at one above RowNdx

            If Cells(RowNdx, "b").Value = Cells(RowNdx2, "b").Value And _
                Cells(RowNdx, "C").Value = Cells(RowNdx2, "C").Value And _
                Cells(RowNdx, "E").Value = Cells(RowNdx2, "E").Value And _
                Cells(RowNdx, "F").Value <> Cells(RowNdx2, "F").Value Then
                Rows(RowNdx2).Delete 'this is where i need help
            End If

        Next RowNdx2
    Next RowNdx

End Sub
```

Comment: Why is line 17 (contains `Feb 20` deleted in your second group?

Comment: the dates change, but never mind. mr R3uK helped me out. but thank you anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Sheet1` to the name of your sheet in `Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` :

```
Sub del_doops()
Dim RowNdx As Long
Dim RowNdx2 As Long
Dim wS As Worksheet

Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
With wS
    For RowNdx = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        For RowNdx2 = RowNdx - 1 To 1 Step -1   'Begin at one above RowNdx
            If .Cells(RowNdx, "B").Value = .Cells(RowNdx2, "B").Value And _
                    .Cells(RowNdx, "C").Value = .Cells(RowNdx2, "C").Value And _
                    .Cells(RowNdx, "E").Value = .Cells(RowNdx2, "E").Value And _
                    .Cells(RowNdx, "F").Value <> .Cells(RowNdx2, "F").Value Then
                If .Cells(RowNdx, "D").Value <> vbNullString Then
                    .Rows(RowNdx).Delete
                Else
                    If .Cells(RowNdx2, "D").Value = vbNullString Then .Rows(RowNdx2).Delete
                End If
            End If
        Next RowNdx2
    Next RowNdx
End With 'wS
End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing, pure genius

Comment: @aj_bk : Glad I could help! ;) Just a thing for you, notice the `.` in `.Cells(` and `.Range(` it's thanks to the `With wS` and it is the easiest way to properly reference the sheet you are working in! ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub del_doops()
Dim RowNdx As Long
Dim RowNdx2 As Long
For RowNdx = Range("A1:f1").End(xlDown).Row To 2 Step -1
    For RowNdx2 = RowNdx - 1 To 1 Step -1   'Begin at one above RowNdx
        If Cells(RowNdx, "B").Value = Cells(RowNdx2, "B").Value And _
        Cells(RowNdx, "C").Value = Cells(RowNdx2, "C").Value And _
        Cells(RowNdx, "E").Value = Cells(RowNdx2, "E").Value And _
        Cells(RowNdx, "F").Value = Cells(RowNdx2, "F").Value Then
            If Cells(RowNdx, "D").Value = vbNullString And _
            Cells(RowNdx2, "D").Value <> vbNullString Then
                Rows(RowNdx2).Delete
            Else
                Rows(RowNdx).Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next RowNdx2
Next RowNdx
End Sub
```